# The probability that a random integer is prime to a given integer $m$ is $\frac{\phi(m)}m$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, number-theory, limits, arithmetic-functions

Let $N_m(x)$ denote the number of positive integers not exceeding $x$ that are relatively prime to $m$ , then how to prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{N_m(x)}x=\dfrac{\phi (m)}m$ , where $\phi(.)$ is the Euler's phi function ?

Answer (score 1):

**Some hints**

1. There are exactly $\varphi(m)$ integers less than $m$ and coprime to $m$
2. For every $k$ there are exactly $\varphi(m)$ integers in the interval $[km,(k+1)m-1]$ coprime to $m$, Indeed every integer $i\in [km,(k+1)m-1]$ can be written in the form $i=km+t$ with $0\leq t<m$ and $\gcd(t,m)=\gcd(i,m)$ so every coprime $i$ gives us a com prime $t$ less than $m$ and the converse still correct, so the number of comprime integers with $m$ in the two intervals is the same.
3. Given a large integer $x=Km+r$ with $r\leq m$ we partition the interval $[0,x]$ in $k+1$ intervales:
   $$[0,m-1],[m,2m-1],[2m,3m-1],\cdots\cdots\cdots,[(K-1)m,Km-1],[Km,Km+r] $$
   the first $k$ intervals contain each $\varphi(m)$ coprime to $m$ and the last inteval contain no more than $\varphi(m)$ so:
   $$K\varphi(m)\leq N_m(x)\leq (K+1)\varphi(m) $$

and don't forget that :$K=\left \lfloor\frac{x}{m}\right\rfloor$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{K}{x}=\frac{1}{m}$

Comment: Do you mean $[km, (k+1)m]$?

Comment: @Elaqqad : What is $n$ ?

Comment: Every thing is fixed now I hope, thanks for your observations

Comment: @Elaqqad: Could you please elaborate on the 2nd hint ?

Comment: Is it all clear now!

Comment: @Elaqqad : I think you mean $\lim _{x \to \infty} \dfrac{K}x = \dfrac 1{m}$ in the last line and also you mean $x=Km+r$ with $0 \le r \le m-1$ ... apart from that it is awesome , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $n$ is relatively prime to $m$ iff $n \mod m$ is.

Answer (score 0):

This  question can  be  answered rigorously  using the  Wiener-Ikehara
Theorem. Suppose the prime factorization of $m$ is
$$m = \prod_p p^v.$$
Suppose we set
$$\Lambda(s) = \sum_{\gcd(n,m)=1} \frac{1}{n^s}.$$

By inspection we get the following Euler product for $\Lambda(s)$:
$$\Lambda(s) = \zeta(s) \prod_p \left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right).$$

Then by the [Wiener-Ikehara theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Ikehara_theorem) we have that
$$\sum_{n\le x, \; \gcd(m,n)=1} 1
\sim  \prod_p \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) \times x.$$

It follows that
$$\frac{1}{x} \sum_{n\le x, \; \gcd(m,n)=1} 1
\sim \prod_p \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) =
\frac{\varphi(m)}{m}.$$

**Remark.** The variable $p$ in the above ranges over the prime factors of $m$ (as opposed to all primes).

Comment: This question can also be answered rigorously *not* using Wiener-Ikehara theorem.

Comment: I apologize, I see the error in my wording.  I did not mean that the theorem is essential.